# OmniAuth not getting added to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

So I am trying to build omniauth into my webpapp:

Omni-Auth gets called from SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)  
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to assignment_path
  end
end
```

And then users are added to the DB in the User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.name = auth["user_info"]["name"]
      user.picture = auth["user_info"]["profile_image_url"]
      user.screen_name = auth["user_info"]["screen_name"]
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
    end
  end
end
```

The name, uid and provider get added to the DB but unfortunately the picture and screen_name do not get added to the DB.

Can any one help?

Comment: you have the necessary fields in your migration?

Comment: I solved the problem see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I was accessing the hash using the wrong parameters.

Comment: Been there before. This little trick is handy in these situations: `raise params.to_yaml`. Or, in the case of OmniAuth: `raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml`